# Filter Python log for only lines from certain files

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have a Python project that shares a single log. Unfortunately, sometimes I want to read through the log, but only for events from certain files. I wrote the following code to solve this problem, but it's ugly as hell. Essentially, it just uses a blacklist of files to ignore. I could improve it by giving it an `__init__` where a black or whitelist could be passed as a variable, but I just wanted to check if there was a simple solution to this problem before I put polish on it.

```
class FocusedLog:
    ''' Iterate through only the parts of the log we care about. '''
    def __iter__(self):
        with open('/tmp/{}.shared.log'.format(os.path.basename(__file__)), 'r') as raw:
            skip = False
            for line in raw:
                if line.startswith('2021-08'):
                    skip = False
                if 'hpack' in line or 'selenium' in line or 'urllib' in line or 'statsapi' in line:
                    skip = True
                # TODO Filter out extraneous files.
                if not skip:#True:#'hpack' not in line and 'selenium' not in line:
                    yield line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up with. The other answer was helpful though.

```
import re

class FocusedLog:
    ''' Iterate through only the parts of the log from files
        in the given whitelist. '''

    def __init__(self, whitelist, fname):
        self.whitelist = whitelist
        self.fname = fname

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.fname, 'r') as raw:
            skip = True
            big_regex = '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (INFO|DEBUG|ERROR|WARNING|CRITICAL) (\S*) (.*)$'
            pat = re.compile(big_regex)
            for line in raw:
                if pat.match(line):
                    skip = True
                    match = pat.match(line)
                    src = match.group(3)
                    if src in self.whitelist:
                        skip = False
                if not skip:
                    yield line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = '/tmp/{}.shared.log'.format(os.path.basename(__file__))
    whitelist = ['__main__', ...]
    for line in FocusedLog(whitelist, fname):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse log files with a custom parser based on `logdissect` module.
Assuming a log format as
`%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s`

The regex to parse it could be
`^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) - (INFO|ERROR|WARNING|CRITICAL) - (.*)$`

The code to parse

```
'''
Log format
'%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
'''

from logdissect import parsers,filters

# File contents
'''
2021-08-21 18:06:22,458 - INFO - info message
2021-08-22 18:06:22,458 - WARNING - warn message selenium
2021-08-22 18:06:22,458 - ERROR - error message 
2021-08-22 18:06:22,458 - CRITICAL - critical message hpack
2021-08-22 18:06:22,521 - WARNING - another warn message  urllib statsapi
'''

fpath = '/home/lmc/tmp/test.txt'
dfilter = '2021-08-22'

ownparser = parsers.blank.ParseModule()
ownparser.name = 'custom parser'
ownparser.format_regex = '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) - (INFO|ERROR|WARNING|CRITICAL) - (.*)$'
ownparser.fields = ['ts', 'level', 'message']
ownparser.datestamp_type = 'None'

grepFilter = filters.grep.FilterModule()
data = ownparser.parse_file(fpath)
new_data = grepFilter.filter_data(data, values=['{}.*(?:hpack|selenium|urllib|statsapi)'.format(dfilter)])
for m in new_data['entries']: 
    print(m['message'])
```

The output:

```
warn message selenium
critical message hpack
another warn message  urllib statsapi
```

Comment: I'll probably make this the accepted answer. I just need time to check it out some more.

Comment: This didn't print anything when I ran it on my machine, but I have some time to focus on this issue today, so I'll try to do my own answer todayish.